how to find pg_resetwal util for postgresql
According to https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/15/app-pgresetwal?lang=en in PostgreSQL 15 should be a pg_resetwal utility, but it is nowhere to be found.
I installed different versions of PostgreSQL fron official repository (15, 16, 17) and searched in /usr/lib/postgresql/[15, 16, 17]/bin
Only the utilities below are available to me:

pg_archivecleanup
pg_buildext
pg_conftool
pg_dropcluster
pg_isready
pg_receivexlog
pg_restore
pg_upgradecluster
pg_backupcluster
pg_config
pg_createcluster
pg_dump pg_lsclusters
pg_recvlogical
pg_restorecluster
pg_virtualenv
pg_basebackup
pg_config.libpq-dev
pg_ctlcluster
pg_dumpall
pg_receivewal
pg_renamecluster
pg_updatedicts

Could it be that something needs to be installed separately?

No, it should be there. But don't run it, it will corrupt your database.

Should be there.  What flavor of linux, and what method did you use to install?
